# Sent response as they come to browser

Tags: java, atmosphere

In my application , when a request is sent there happens a sequence of calls to database from the server and only after the entire calls complete results are sent back.

As opposed to this behavior , I want the response from database to be sent back to the browser "on arrival".
So current behaviour is as below

```
Request (server from browser) -> 
data request #1 ( database from server) ->  
data request #2 ( database from server) ->  
data request #3 ( database from server) ->  
Response (#1 + #2 + #3) ( server to browser)
```

Instead i need

```
Request (server from browser) -> 
data request #1 ( database from server) ->  
Response (#1) ( server to browser) ->
data request #2 ( database from server) ->  
Response (#2) ( server to browser) ->
data request #3 ( database from server) ->  
Response (#3) ( server to browser) ->
Connection disconnect
```

How can  i achieve this using atmosphere or some other library.
My server is in java.

Comment: Isn't the second approach the standard way? How did you implement waiting for all requests to be sent? I guess you could just remove that part and send the response immediately after it becomes available (data is read, response is built etc.).

Comment: Is this over HTTP? What kind of payload are you planning on returning (XML, JSON, HTML, other....?)

Comment: @Thomas - The second approach needs to be implemented using multiple web calls. I am trying to avoid it. For a request / response model , there is only 1 response for a request.

Comment: @XSen - Its over http and its JSON